# Random Digit Generator Help (Java)

Tags: java, random, input, output

I have written a code that is generating random numbers based on user input. For example, if the user says they want the program to generate 3 random digits for them, and they want it to do it 3 times, the output will look like this:

1 4 5

2 6 5

3 4 5

The code that I've written would display this as:

1

4

5

2

6

5

3

4

5

How do I make them display as 3 numbers wide? Here's my code:

```
 if (gameType == 3)

    //for loop to generate random numbers     
    for (int i = 1; i <=numGames; i = i + 1){

        for(int j = 1; j <= numGames * 3; j = j + 1 ){
            ranNums = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);

            //Print random numbers to user
            System.out.println(ranNums);
```

As always, thank you! - I added to the post to help you understand more of what I need. Please let me know if you require more info to help me!

Comment: Look up print vs println, simple as that.

Comment: 3 numbers wide should be static or it should be defined by user?

Comment: 3 numbers wide defined by user. User has option of choosing 3, 4, or 5 digits (simulates pick-2, 4, or 5 lotto game). System generates 3 random numbers for pick 3 if user wants to play 1 game. The part that I'm struggling with is when the user wants to play more than 1 game, I need it to print the next 3 digits below the previous 3, not beside it. Almost if I need a print statement, then a println. I'm so confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally loop should look like:

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= numGames; i = i + 1) {

            for (int j = 1; j<= gameType; j = j + 1) {
                int ranNums = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
                System.out.print(ranNums + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: that still doesn't do it for me....I need it to print 3 digits, then "\n" then 3 more digits then "\n", etc.... The number of rows to print conditional here won't really set a number of rows. The user will enter gameType, which determines how many digits are produced. Then, the user will enter numGames, which determines how many times they want the system to print their game type. How would I do this? Like I need a conditional that says after the loop prints three numbers (123), then it will make a new line "\n" and print 3 more....

Comment: @StevenChristman edited it according to your comment. Not sure if I got you rightly

Comment: You sir are a savior! I have been ready to pull my hair out over this for the past two days.... So simple, and now I feel so dumb. Thank you SO much for your help. I knew coming to this site would pay off. Have a good day!